# MVC ignore parameters in files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

You have a file a static file in your server, in our case, an image
https://signtul.com/content/img/signature-boundary-08972bce-d646-483d-a436-d8ceea7ab034.png

This file is used inside the Microsoft OWA. If for some reason outlook can't fetch the file it tries again using a retry count.

OWA adds a paramater in the request, so it try with a url like this

https://signtul.com/content/img/signature-boundary-08972bce-d646-483d-a436-d8ceea7ab034.png&retrycount=2

Its unfortunate the OWA adds `&retryCount=` instead `?retryCount=`, because that makes MVC things its a different file and the user receives a 404.

So.. any way to ignore that additional parameter for static files/images?

Comment: Can you just add question mark in the end like ".png?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that since your query string is malformed, IIS will choke on it before ASP.NET (or MVC) even has a chance to intervene.

Typically, MVC does not handle static content at all and it is best if you leave that task to IIS for performance reasons. The simplest way to solve this is to use the [IIS rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to ensure the URL is rewritten to a usable one (with a `?`). You can make a single rule to handle multiple file types quite easily. The below example will work on `.png`, `.jpg`, `.gif`, `.js`, and `.css` files - you can add other extensions as needed for your requirements.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite static content with URL querystring starting with &">
          <match url="^(.+?(?:\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.js|\.css))&amp;(.+?)$"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" appendQueryString="false" url="{R:1}?{R:2}"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Basically, the above looks for any of the aforementioned extensions followed immediately by an ampersand and any other text (presumably the query string). In only that case, it will capture both the URL path including extension and the query string (ignoring the ampersand). Then it rebuilds the URL using a question mark instead of an ampersand before passing it on to its handler.

Note that the regular expression will ignore correctly specified query strings, so the rule only applies to malformed query strings.

Answer (score 0):

I see two solution to your problem

1. append all file names with "?" in the end to be **signature-boundary-08972bce-d646-483d-a436-d8ceea7ab034.png?**
2. I would create route to catch all "/content/img/signature-boundary-*" and get input parameter as a string and since you expect to be png or any other file name you can write some kind of cleanup of all garbage. I actually had similar problem when i got lots of wrong parameters from search engines (because of invalid share stuff in my case it was something with #) so it was one possible fix because i was not able to control this input

Comment: I'd rather a generic solution, all images in content, not specific for each image.

Comment: @RicardoPolo you can do that with any filetype ..pdf,png, jpg, csv, etc.

Comment: I mean your solutions is specific for one file. I want a solution that works for every file in the content folder. I dont want to make changes in filenames our create a route per each file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it solves the problem as I have no experience with OWA.

Can you try adding a slag querystring at the end of the all images like:

https://signtul.com/content/img/signature-boundary-08972bce-d646-483d-a436-d8ceea7ab034.png?x=0

I hope the subsequent request to look like:

https://signtul.com/content/img/signature-boundary-08972bce-d646-483d-a436-d8ceea7ab034.png?x=0&retrycount=2

In such case, it should solve your problem.